# Why is there no "share" link on the mobile version of the site?

Tags: feature-request

Given the richness of mobile browsing, and the power of the devices they run on; shouldn't there be a "share" link on questions on the mobile version of the site?

Comment: Come on. Share with the feature in the OS ;)

Comment: @VitorCanova Yeah, I know, but then I couldn't get the [publicist](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/badges/61/publicist) badge :)

Comment: The only thing you can do now is to add a slash at the end of the link followed by your user id number. In your case this would be **/106**.